# Undefined error inside function of Order component

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have developed a page which contains a single recipe page and there is an order button. When order button is clicked the order of that recipe should be shown along with the price just side of recipe section. But I get **sorry recipe no longer available**. In the render section inside Order Component i get an id of order. But why i get an undefined error inside renderOrder function(this.props.order[key] and this.props.recipe[key]). Why is that so?

```
export default class SingleRecipe extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { order: {} };
    }

    getMeteorData(){
        let data = {};
        let recipehandle = Meteor.subscribe('singlerecipe',this.props.slug);
        if(recipehandle.ready()){
            data.recipe = Recipes.findOne({_id:this.props.slug});
        }
        return data;
    }


    addToOrder(key){
        this.state.order[key] = this.state.order[key]+1 || 1;;
        this.setState({
            order:this.state.order
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {recipe}=this.data;
        const {order}=this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s6">
                        {recipe.nameOfRecipe}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col s6">
                        <Order order={order} recipe={recipe} removeFromOrder = {this.removeFromOrder} /> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default class Order extends Component {
    renderOrder(key){
        let order = this.props.order[key]; 
        let recipe = this.props.recipe[key]; // get undefined
        let removeButton = <button onClick={this.props.removeFromOrder.bind(this,key)}>&times;</button>;
        if(!recipe){
            return  <li key={key}>Sorry, recipe no longer available! {removeButton}</li>
        }

        return(
                <li key={key}>
                    <span>
                         <CSSTransitionGroup component="span" transitionName="count" transitionLeaveTimeout={250} transitionEnterTimeout={250} className="count">
                            <span key={count}>{count}</span>
                         </CSSTransitionGroup>
                         {recipe.nameOfRecipe}{removeButton}
                    </span>
                </li>
            )       
    }
    render() {
        let orderId = Object.keys(this.props.order); // returns the id 
        return (
            <div className="order-wrap">
                <h2 className="order-title">Your Order</h2>
                <CSSTransitionGroup
                      className="order"
                      component="ul"
                      transitionName="order"
                      transitionEnterTimeout={100}
                      transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
                    >
                   {orderId.map(item=>this.renderOrder(item))}
                </CSSTransitionGroup>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing `this.props.recipe[key] to this.props.recipe`will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
{orderId.map(this.renderOrder)}
```

change to

```
 {orderId.map(item=>this.renderOrder(item))}
```

Comment: when i hit order button, if(!recipe) block executes.

Comment: let removeButton = <button onClick={()=>this.props.removeFromOrder(key)}>&times;</button>;

Comment: Your code is not complete.Such as 'const {recipe}=this.data;',this.data?,there is no this.data existed.

Comment: still same return  <li key={key}>Sorry, recipe no longer available! {removeButton}</li> executes while clicking order button.

Comment: but const{recipe} is working properly while fetching recipe data  and this.data is from meteor getMeteorData function.

Comment: I cannot find where getMeteorData is used.

Comment: it is in SingleRecipe component just after the initialization of constructor.